# Python serial permission issue

Tags: python, serial, arduino

I'm trying to connect my Arduino to my RPi through python and PySerial, and I'm using the following code:

```
import serial
ser = serial.Serial('/dev/serial/ttyACM0', 9600)
```

and I was getting an issue along the lines of the program not being able to open the COM port due to a permission issue

```
Traceback(Most recent call last):
    File "<pyshell#2>", line 1, in <module>
        ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM0', 9600)
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/serial/serialutil.py", line 260, in___init__
        self.open()
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/serial/serialposix.py", line 276, in open
        raise SerialException("could not open port %s: %s* % (self._port, msg))
SerialException: could not open port /dev/ttyACM0: [Errno 13] Permission denied:'/dev/ttyACM0'
```

So according to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23669855/linux-pyserial-could-not-open-port-dev-ttyama0-no-such-file-or-directory) I substituted the /dev/ttyACM0 to what I found in /dev/serial/by-id.  That turned out to be the id

```
usb-Arduino__www.arduino.cc__0043_7434353035171C0B2-if00
```

to make

```
/dev/serial/by-id/usb-Arduino__www.arduino.cc__0043_7434353035171C0B2-if00
```

and now I am receiving the same error in the python program, which seemed to work for the asker in the previous question.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can start python as root, for a quick and dirty workaround:

```
sudo python
```

and then

```
import serial
....
```

Of course, this is not the best way to go, it would be better to try setting different permissions on the device itself, like

```
sudo chmod 777 /dev/ttyACM0
```

or (for exclusive access to the user pi)

```
sudo chown pi:pi /dev/ttyACM0
```

or similar. You can get some more information [here](http://www.gphoto.org/doc/manual/permissions-serial.html).

Answer (score 10):

@LiWi's answer will work temporarily, but the permission change will be lost once the device is removed or the server rebooted.

A permanent solution is to add your user to the `dialout` group, which will allow it to access serial devices.

```
sudo usermod -a -G dialout youruser
```

Answer (score 0):

i had the same probleme ; so I figure out another way to read RX flue ; here is the code :

```
   import os
   #....

    rx='0'  #erase old data
   ch = os.popen("sudo cat /dev/ttyAMA0", "r")  # send terminal commande with
            root permission and save the resulte in "ch"
    while(j<20):  # for me 20 lines are suffisent 
        rx+= ch.readline()   # read line and concat lines
        j+=1       # next loop/line
   ch.close()    # close ch
```